# Getting wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am learning MapReduce, I wrote a program which computes the total duration of booking done by member & non-member. I passed all the possible job configuration required, but when running the hadoop command, it throws wrong value class. I tried searching many solution in stackoverflow, but couldn't debug the problem. The Output of the Map and Input of the Reducer are correct.
Can someone help me with it?

```
public class BixiMontrealAnalysis {

    public static class BixiMapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String csvAttributes[] = line.toString().split(",");
            int isMember = 0;
            int duration = 0;
            try {
                duration = Integer.parseInt(csvAttributes[4]);
                isMember = Integer.parseInt(csvAttributes[5]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Will Emit 0,0");
            }
            context.write(new IntWritable(isMember), new IntWritable(duration));
        }
    }

    public static class BixiReducer extends Reducer <IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, LongWritable> {
        public void reduce(IntWritable isMember, Iterable <IntWritable> combinedDurationByIsMember, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0L;
            for (IntWritable duration: combinedDurationByIsMember) {
                sum = sum + (long) duration.get();
            }
            context.write(isMember, new LongWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "bix-montreal-job");
        job.setJarByClass(BixiMontrealAnalysis.class);
        job.setMapperClass(BixiMapper.class);

        job.setCombinerClass(BixiReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(BixiReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

I am expecting the output as K,V as `0, sum of duration` & `1, sum of duration`

CSV Content

```
start_date,start_station_code,end_date,end_station_code,duration_sec,is_member
2019-07-01 00:00:03,6014,2019-07-01 00:04:26,6023,262,1
2019-07-01 00:00:07,6036,2019-07-01 00:34:54,6052,2087,0
2019-07-01 00:00:11,6018,2019-07-01 00:06:48,6148,396,1
2019-07-01 00:00:12,6202,2019-07-01 00:17:25,6280,1032,1
2019-07-01 00:00:15,6018,2019-07-01 00:06:57,6148,401,0
2019-07-01 00:00:20,6248,2019-07-01 00:15:40,6113,920,1
2019-07-01 00:00:37,6268,2019-07-01 00:15:00,6195,862,0
```

Below is the stack trace

```
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner$OutputConverter.write(Task.java:1691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
    at com.onboarding.hadoop.BixiMontrealAnalysis$BixiReducer.reduce(BixiMontrealAnalysis.java:43)
    at com.onboarding.hadoop.BixiMontrealAnalysis$BixiReducer.reduce(BixiMontrealAnalysis.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
job.setCombinerClass(BixiReducer.class);
```

I have set `Combiner` Class same as the `Reducer`, which shouldn't be, taking reference to standard WordCount Problem. I did a study about `Combiner` and figured out that the use of `Combiner` class is to produce intermediate record, so the load on `Reducer` is less.